# How To Write Unit Test For Method Returning JsonResult With RenderPartialViewToString?

Tags: unit-testing, model-view-controller, rhino-mocks, mvccontrib

If you look at the example at this link:

http://www.atlanticbt.com/blog/asp-net-mvc-using-ajax-json-and-partialviews/

How would one write a unit test for the JsonAdd method?  I have a similar situation in my own code, but the RenderPartialViewToString errors when calling:

ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView

I've tried different ways of trying to stub that call to no avail.  Any help appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ViewEninges is a static class, you can't mock it with RhinoMocks.  I think your best bet is to create a "partial view renderer" interface.  An interface is mockable so you'll be able to stub out the complexity of rendering the view.  Here's some quick pseudo-code thrown together.

First, define the partial view renderer interface:

```
public interface IRenderPartialView
{
    string Render(string viewName, object model);
}
```

Then, change your base class' RenderPartialViewToString to be the implementation of IRenderPartialView.Render:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller, IRenderPartialView
{
...
    public string Render(string viewName, object model)
    {
        // same code as RenderPartialViewToString
    }
}
```

Now we need to change your controller constructors so we can inject an IRenderPartialView during testing -- but use the base class one during production.  We can accomplish this by using a pair of constructors:

```
public class YourController : BaseController
{
        private IRenderPartialView partialRenderer;

        public YourController()
        {
            SetRenderer(this);
        }

        public YourController(IRenderPartialView partialRenderer)
        {
            SetRenderer(partialRenderer);
        }

        private void SetRenderer(IRenderPartialView partialRenderer)
        {
            this.partialRenderer = this;
        }
}
```

Now, JsonAdd can call the partial view renderer:

```
public JsonResult JsonAdd(AddPersonViewModel AddPersonModel)
{
    ...
    return Json(new
    {
        Success = true,
        Message = "The person has been added!",
        PartialViewHtml = partialRenderer.Render("PersonList", new PersonListViewModel {PersonList = _personList})
    });
}
```

So, during testing, you'll mock out an `IRenderPartialView` and send that to the constructor that accepts an `IRenderPartialView`.  During production, when ASP.NET MVC calls your default constructor, it will use the controller as the renderer (which has the implementation of `IRenderPartialView.Render` inside the base class).

Comment: I was in the process of isolating the dependency to an interface, but had not quite gotten to the multiple constructor idea.  Works great...thanks Patrick!

Answer (score 6):

I had a lot of trouble to make unit test working with RenderPartialViewToString.
I succeeded by doing 2 things.
I had to mock the view engine and the controller context.

Here the code :

```
public ViewEngineResult SetupViewContent(string viewName, string viewHtmlContent)
    {
        var mockedViewEngine = new Mock<IViewEngine>();
        var resultView = new Mock<IView>();

        resultView.Setup(x => x.Render(It.IsAny<ViewContext>(), It.IsAny<TextWriter>()))
            .Callback<ViewContext, TextWriter>((v, t) =>
            {
                t.Write(viewHtmlContent);
            });

        var viewEngineResult = new ViewEngineResult(resultView.Object, mockedViewEngine.Object);
        mockedViewEngine.Setup(x => x.FindPartialView(It.IsAny<ControllerContext>(), viewName, It.IsAny<bool>()))
            .Returns<ControllerContext, string, bool>((controller, view, useCache) =>
            {
                return viewEngineResult;
            });

        mockedViewEngine.Setup(x => x.FindView(It.IsAny<ControllerContext>(), viewName, It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<bool>()))
            .Returns<ControllerContext, string, string, bool>((controller, view, masterName, useCache) =>
            {
                return viewEngineResult;
            });

        ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(mockedViewEngine.Object);
        return viewEngineResult;
    }

    public void SetContext(ref PointCollecteLivraisonController controller)
    {
        SetupViewContent("MyViewName", "TheViewContent");

        var httpContextBase = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        var httpRequestBase = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
        var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
        var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
        var routes = new RouteCollection();
        RouteConfigurator.RegisterRoutes(routes);
        var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "PointCollecteLivraison");
        routeData.Values.Add("action", "RechercheJson");

        httpContextBase.Setup(x => x.Response).Returns(response.Object);
        httpContextBase.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(httpRequestBase.Object);
        httpContextBase.Setup(x => x.Session).Returns(session.Object);
        session.Setup(x => x["somesessionkey"]).Returns("value");
        httpRequestBase.Setup(x => x.Form).Returns(new NameValueCollection());
        controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(httpContextBase.Object, routeData, controller);
        controller.Url = new UrlHelper(new RequestContext(controller.HttpContext, routeData), routes);
    }
```

And that is the way i use it all :

```
PointCollecteLivraisonController controller = new PointCollecteLivraisonController();
SetContext(ref controller);
```

Here are my sources :
View engine mocking : http://thoai-nguyen.blogspot.fr/2011/04/test-mock-mvc-view-engine.html

Controller context mocking : [ASP.NET MVC - Unit testing RenderPartialViewToString() with Moq framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621961/asp-net-mvc-unit-testing-renderpartialviewtostring-with-moq-framework)

Hope this help.

Comment: Very good work. For everyone having problem with RouteConfigurator. RegisterRoutes is by default in Global.asax.cs, part of MvcApplication (default) Thank for this code, it helped me a lot.