# Unit Tests Mock ControllerContext HttpContext No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.View...ITempDataDictionaryFactory' has been registered

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, moq, xunit

In my test project i am using xUnit with Moq.

now i want to unit test these piece of code in the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl = null)
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    return View();
}
```

As you see it uses the `SignOutAsync` of the `HttpContext`.

I tried so many solution such as [ASP.NET MVC - Unit testing, mocking HttpContext without using any mock framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661722/asp-net-mvc-unit-testing-mocking-httpcontext-without-using-any-mock-framework) but didn't work for me, since i dont have access to the `HttpRequestBase`

Using Moq, i am trying to mock this `HttpContext`, so i tried this:

```
public static Mock<HttpContext> GenerateFakeHttpContext()
{
   var mockHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContext>();
   var authServiceMock = new Mock<IAuthenticationService>();
   authServiceMock.Setup(_ => _.SignOutAsync(
                                   It.IsAny<HttpContext>(), 
                                   It.IsAny<string>(), 
                                   It.IsAny<AuthenticationProperties>()))
       .Returns(Task.FromResult((object)null));

   var serviceProviderMock = new Mock<IServiceProvider>();

   serviceProviderMock.Setup(_ => _.GetService(typeof(IAuthenticationService)))
           .Returns(authServiceMock.Object);

   mockHttpContext.Setup(x => x.RequestServices)
           .Returns(serviceProviderMock.Object);

   return mockHttpContext;
}
```

inspired from this question :
[MSTest: Unit Testing HttpContext.SignoutAsync for the logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71168289/mstest-unit-testing-httpcontext-signoutasync-for-the-logout/71168290#71168290), after a multiple research.

The test method is like this:

```
public async Task Login_ShouldSignOutToClearCoockies_WhenReturnUrlIsNullOrNotNull()
{
    //Arrange
    _sutAccountController
    .ControllerContext.HttpContext = TestsHelper.GenerateFakeHttpContext().Object;

    //Act
    var result = await _sutAccountController.Login(null);

    //Assert
    result.Should().NotBeNull();
}
```

but in runtime i get this exception:

```
   Duration: 367 ms

  Message: 
System.InvalidOperationException : No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ITempDataDictionaryFactory' has been registered.

  Stack Trace: 
ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
Controller.get_TempData()
Controller.View(String viewName, Object model)
Controller.View(String viewName)
Controller.View()
AccountController.Login(String returnUrl) line 38
AccountControllerTests.Login_ShouldSignOutToClearCoockies_WhenReturnUrlIsNullOrNotNull() line 46
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
```

if there's a better way to mock the **HttpContext**.

Thanks.

Comment: You could try to, instead of mocking the HttpContext, just using a `DefaultHttpContext` and setting your mock service provider to the RequestServices instance of that (mocking a class is always a tad complicated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally, found a solution by mocking the controller TempData

Source: [Mocking a TempData in ASP.NET Core in MSTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52181767/mocking-a-tempdata-in-asp-net-core-in-mstest)

```
var tempData = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures
.TempDataDictionary(httpContext, Mock.Of<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ITempDataProvider>());
tempData["ReturnUrl"] = "";

_sutController.ControllerContext.HttpContext = httpContext;
_sutController.TempData = tempData
```